# Tooljet issue: Tooljet interface is becoming unresponsive when i try to visualise the query results

Tags: issue-tracking

I have self-hosted tooljet on AWS EC2 by using tooljet official AMI from marketplace.
tooljet is up and running fine and i'm able to connect to the databases aswell.

FYI, i have given 8vcpu and 16gm memory to my ec2 server, For RDS it is 2vCPU and 4gb RAM. And there's no issue in both server and rds load, all metrics are fine. And there are no errors in logs aswell.

When i try to query something it is giving the query data in JSON/RAW format through SQL mode.
But if i want to visualise my query results then i need to add table component in tooljet interface.
After adding the table component it started breaking the interface, the page is becoming unresponsive and giving the below error if i inspect

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 451 (Unavailable For Legal Reasons)
/api/custom-styles/app:1

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 451 (Unavailable For Legal Reasons)**

The issue is happening only with the visualisation part. Can anyone help on this